# Armature shifts between Pose mode and Edit mode

Tags: rigging, armature, splines

I'm using s Spline IK system to create the spine for a creature I'm making, but when I activated the Spline IK, some parts of the same seem to shrink or shift a bit. Which slitghly deforms my mesh a bit without even moving any bones.

[image]

Here is a GIF showing what I mean: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmycz5s1ddka5cu/IK%20shift.gif?dl=0

Any idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: Please show your work in the question if possible. Screen capture or gif or etc.

Comment: Gif is on that link.

Comment: You can still take the effort to place an image in your question.

Comment: How do you post a picture here? I didn't saw any upload button.

Comment: Edit question.  Header will show mountains and sun for image.  You may comment if you do not find within 33 seconds.

Comment: Please show in your question your successful spline constraint for neck and failed for tail.  Show origins for both curves.

Comment: I added the picture, and the origin point of both is at the center of the scene, they both using a deform rig and control rig. Along with empties that serve as hooks for every bone joint which is then controlled by the control rig.

Comment: I would like to clearly see the origins of the curves.  I cannot see them.  Perhaps other people can.  Still waiting as I do other activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

Make sure

- Align origins of curves with Snap the first vertex position of curve.
- you have not  repositioned the bones when you want to see standard rest position.

---

I believe you should either have

- Separate Back spine concept and Separate Tail concept for Control concept. Fresh Start. Clear preference.
- Switch direction of spine bones.  Less Preference.

The neck bones are reasonable.  The spine/tail bones are Blender Bites Ya.  Your current spine/tail is like the undesirable metaphor about the tail wagging the dog.  Note that I do not want address unrelated topics if possible, but this issue appears large.

Make sure you have not moved any bones in pose mode for the particular frame.    The point of pose mode is to place bones in different positions.

You may need to use Menu ... Pose Clear Transforms Location.  You may need to delete any keyframes.

[image]

Use the setting

Chain Offset enabled in the Bone Constraint Panel.  This will maintain the position of the root of the first affected bone.  The first affected bone will be the bone further up the parent chain as determined by chain length.

[image]

Successful use of Spline Constraint. Image above.

Additionally
For Precise placement in a different manner be very aware of your origin on the curve.

[image]

Align origin to first point on curve. Snap is used for precision. Image above.

Curve origin should be first point on curve. Be precise with the use of [Snap].  Edit mode curve, Select first point, snap cursor to selected, object mode, Transform Origin to Cursor.

It seems seems you made an effort to align with eyeball which is semi precise.  Snap is 100% precise.

Comment: The correct steps have been shown above.  Well perhaps attempted.

Comment: I have use snapped. In fact, the neck on this character has a IK Spline Spine working perfecly. Now the one that controlls the spine and tail is what causing the shifting. If you want I can share the blend file so you can have a look.

Comment: No bones have been moved in pose mode, I made sure of it. And there are no keyframes. I'm the in rigging process, no keyframes whatsoever have been made.

Comment: Okay, I rebuilt it from the ground up and now there are no issues any more. There is shifting on the back leg but that was caused by the IK on leg not having the pole target correctly set. So I'm going to assume I somehow screwed up the placement of some of the hooks somehow. This is also just an experiment, I wasn't sure if I wanted the tail and spine separate, because in reality those would be connected, so I decided to experiment with that first. But maybe it might achieve better results with the tail having it's own separate spline. But thank you for the help, the chain offset did help.

Comment: ¿Did you switch direction of butt bones to tip of tail bones? Wagging starts at the butt under most circumstances.  Unless the beast is lifting its body from tail or hanging from tail. That is another different question.

Comment: I'm currently doing that, I'm building the spine and tail all from the ground up based on what you have suggested. I'll post a screenshot of it when it's done.

Comment: Well, I was able to get them working individually, but together they all just fall apart. I really wanted a Maya style rig in Blender for animation, but I don't think blender can actually do that. I think I'm just going to go with a simple FK rig with it for animation. Been spending three days on this thing with little progress. Unless you are willing to share some tricks for rigging in blender. You seem to be knowledgeable about rigging in Blender and there is barely any information online. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: When you show your new work then people will understand your new problem.  Post a new question.  A new question with a fresh start.

Comment: You may be at the breakthrough point.  Blender can probably do what you want.  Intense learning curve.

Comment: Alright, I'll be posting a new question in a few minutes.